# Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a page coded in React with NextJS hooks, when I try to render a page the error says what's in the title, I presume because the object which I'm mapping is empty/undefined on first load. I added "?" to every map I have on the page and it's still giving me this error... I noticed that if I stay on that page after it gives me error and press "Ctrl + shift + r" the page loads normally. What could be causing this?

```
import {Fragment, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
import DashboardPage from "../../../../components/components/dashboard/DashboardPage";
import LayoutDashboard from "../../../../components/layout/LayoutDashboard";
import React from "react";
import Pusher from "pusher-js";
import useSWR, {mutate} from "swr";

const fetcher = async () => {
  const response1 = await fetch("API");
  const data1 = await response1.json();

  const response3 = await fetch("API");
  const data3 = await response3.json();

  const response4 = await fetch("API");
  const data4 = await response4.json();

  const props = {
    showItemsOnOrder: data1,
    dashboardCardInfo: data3,
    dashboardGraph: data4,
  };
  return props;
};

export default function Dashboard(props) {
  const {data, error} = useSWR("data", fetcher);

  useEffect(() => {
    //Pusher.logToConsole = true;
    var pusher = new Pusher("pshr", {
      cluster: "eu",
    });
    const channel = pusher.subscribe("chnl");
    channel.bind("chnl", function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      mutate("data");
    });
  }, []);

  if (!data) return "loading";
  if (error) return "Error";

  console.log(data);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Head>
        <title>Dashboard</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <link
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@200;300;400;600;700;900&display=swap"
          rel="stylesheet"
        />
      </Head>

      <DashboardPage
        orders={data?.showItemsOnOrder && data.showItemsOnOrder}
        dashboardCards={data?.dashboardCardInfo && data.dashboardCardInfo}
        ordersGraph={data?.dashboardGraph && data.dashboardGraph}
      />
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const response = await fetch(`API`);
  const data = await response.json();

  const tables = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= data[0].restaurantTables; i++) {
    tables.push({
      restaurant: data[0].queryName,
      tableNr: i.toString(),
    });
  }

  return {
    paths: tables.map((tables) => {
      return {
        params: {
          restaurantName: tables.restaurant,
          tableNr: tables.tableNr,
        },
      };
    }),
    fallback: false,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const response = await fetch(`API`);
  const data = await response.json();

  return {
    props: {
      restaurantData: data,
    },
    revalidate: 1,
  };
}
```

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

If I control shift r it reloads normally...

Answer (score 0):

Is it from around this line:

```
paths: tables.map((tables) => {
```

looks like you mean `table` not `tables`

```
paths: tables.map((table) => {
```

Comment: good point but that didn't solve the problem